# Excel 2013 Display list of objects meeting multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

Say I have a transactional list of every purchase made in the last month.

How can I show a list of the customers that have purchased both `Product A` and `Product B`.

I can make a pivot table and filter against the products, but it gives me an A or B list, not A and B.

How can I do this ?

Edit to add data sample and result I wish to see:  (note that actual data is several thousand lines long)

```
Customer Name  |  Purchase Date   |  Product;
Bob            |  02/05/2018      |  Eggs;
Bob            |  02/05/2018      |  Cheese;
Ali            |  02/05/2018      |  Eggs;
Ali            |  02/05/2018      |  Brocoli;
Jon            |  02/05/2018      |  Eggs;
Jon            |  02/05/2018      |  Cheese;
Jon            |  02/05/2018      |  Brocoli;
```

Who purchased Eggs and Cheese between 01/05/2018 and 30/05/2018?

```
Customer Name   |
Bob
Jon
```

Comment: There will many ways to achieve this, but we will be able to best answer it if we can see a sample of data, and what you expect as an outcome

Comment: Thanks Peter!  I tried adding data but not sure how to attached a table.  It formatted it as a paragraph unfortunately and didnt keep my line breaks.

Comment: for future posts, select your table when you enter your question and use Ctrl+K and it will format it as a table (sort of)

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry cannot comment so have to post)

A quick fix, probably not very elegant, but does the job.
Please see the layout here:

[Layout and formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TF5c.png)

I use two pivot tables to get the names that take Eggs and Cheeses, and then use a simple `COUNTIF` formula to calculate the number of appearances in these two pivot tables. If the calculated value is 2 then it meets your criteria.

I'm pretty sure there are better function methods and it's easy to write a macro for that. Let me now if you want more solutions.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, this is good for the basic example I gave, but my ultimate goal is to try and get to a point where I can use something like a Slicer to select multiple products at a time, so I can do some cross-product marketing analysis.  I want to understand which products are purchased most often together.